# Migrating query with rownum from Oracle to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I am trying to migrate my database from oracle to mariadb.

When I remove the select query, it is executing perfectly fine, or else the procedure is showing error.

```
SELECT MSFID, CONVEFEES INTO OUT_MSFID,OUT_CONVEFEES
    FROM
      (SELECT MSF.MSFID 
        (CASE WHEN MSF.CHARGETYPE = 'H' THEN 
                     (CASE WHEN (LV_METRNAMT*((IFNULL(FIXPER,0))/100)) > (IFNULL(FIXAMT,0))  THEN 
                           (LV_METRNAMT*((IFNULL(FIXPER,0))/100))
                       ELSE (IFNULL(FIXAMT,0) )END)
                  WHEN MSF.CHARGETYPE = 'L' THEN 
                      (CASE WHEN (LV_METRNAMT*((IFNULL(FIXPER,0))/100)) > (IFNULL(FIXAMT,0))  THEN 
                            (IFNULL(FIXAMT,0)) 
                        ELSE (LV_METRNAMT*((IFNULL(FIXPER,0))/100))
                        END)
                  ELSE
                    (LV_METRNAMT*((IFNULL(FIXPER,0))/100)) + (IFNULL(FIXAMT,0)) 
                END)

        -- (P_METRNAMT*((IFNULL(DMPER_OFFUS,0)*100)/100))+ (IFNULL(DMFIXAMT_OFFUS,0) * 100) 
        AS CONVEFEES
      FROM VTMEMSF MSF
      WHERE CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN MSF.EFFFROM AND MSF.EFFTILL  AND MSF.SLABUPTO>= LV_METRNAMT AND STOREID=P_STOREID
        AND `MSF.STATUS` = 'A' AND MSF.MSFTYPE='C' -- AND MSF.TRANTYPE=P_TRNTYPE
        ORDER BY SLABUPTO)
     LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: There is no rownum in mysql maybe you need limit 1.

Comment: Include your crash log in the question if you have one. Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information.

Comment: @P.Salmon  yeah i used limit 1. but still it is not executing

Comment: sysdate is also not mysql.

Comment: @P.Salmon that also I changed to CURRENT_DATE()

Comment: Why not edit the question to match the code changes you have made.

Comment: @UmarZaii I don't have any crash log. It is executed in mysql workbench

Comment: @P.Salmon changed it. Kindly view it and suggest some changes incase if you know

Comment: In line comments start with # not --, you need a table alias after ORDER BY SLABUPTO). All else being equal the code should at least syntax with these changes.

Comment: @P.Salmon I am not getting sir. can you brief it

Comment: @P.Salmon - MySQL does have `SYSDATE()`; it usually the same as `CURRENT_DATE()`.

Comment: \`MSF.STATUS\` is incorrectly quoted; you need \`MSF\`.\`STATUS\`.

Comment: "still not executing" -- hanging?  returning 0 rows?  giving an error?  What?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MSFID, CONVEFEES INTO OUT_MSFID,OUT_CONVEFEES
    FROM
      (SELECT MSF.MSFID 
        (CASE WHEN MSF.CHARGETYPE = 'H' THEN 
                     (CASE WHEN (LV_METRNAMT*((IFNULL(FIXPER,0))/100)) > (IFNULL(FIXAMT,0))  THEN 
                           (LV_METRNAMT*((IFNULL(FIXPER,0))/100))
                       ELSE (IFNULL(FIXAMT,0) )END)
                  WHEN MSF.CHARGETYPE = 'L' THEN 
                      (CASE WHEN (LV_METRNAMT*((IFNULL(FIXPER,0))/100)) > (IFNULL(FIXAMT,0))  THEN 
                            (IFNULL(FIXAMT,0)) 
                        ELSE (LV_METRNAMT*((IFNULL(FIXPER,0))/100))
                        END)
                  ELSE
                    (LV_METRNAMT*((IFNULL(FIXPER,0))/100)) + (IFNULL(FIXAMT,0)) 
                END)

        #-- (P_METRNAMT*((IFNULL(DMPER_OFFUS,0)*100)/100))+ (IFNULL(DMFIXAMT_OFFUS,0) * 100) 
        AS CONVEFEES
      FROM VTMEMSF MSF
      WHERE CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN MSF.EFFFROM AND MSF.EFFTILL  AND MSF.SLABUPTO>= LV_METRNAMT AND STOREID=P_STOREID
        AND `MSF.STATUS` = 'A' AND MSF.MSFTYPE='C' #-- AND MSF.TRANTYPE=P_TRNTYPE
        ORDER BY SLABUPTO) s
     LIMIT 1;
```